# When running tests with M2Eclipse source code links in console don't work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, m2eclipse

When an Eclipse project is built using Run as -> Maven Build then Maven looks for unit tests and executes them. If any tests fail then the error is presented as a stacktrace including a link to the source code file. Example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running de.xyz.testing.MainTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.11 sec <<< FAILURE!
testReturnSix(de.xyz.testing.MainTest)  Time elapsed: 0.062 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<6> but was:<7>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
```

The class names are coloured and underlined as links (unfortunately I'm not able to present this in the code snipped above), however these links don't work. This makes running and checking tests with Maven a bit useless and tempts me to use JUnit directly without Maven and treat the Maven testing cycle as necessary evil. But it shouldn't be necessary to use two tools when there is one, right?

My environment is (in case it matters, it's up-to-date):

- Eclipse Oxygen
- M2Eclipse Plugin 1.8
- Maven 3.5
- JUnit 4.12

I cannot find any solution on the web. So what have I possibly forgotten or misconfigured ?

Comment: I would run the tests in Eclipse directly. In my projects I always make sure that everything can be run both from the IDE and from Maven. I see it like IDE is for "humans" (i.e. during development; Eclipse will display test results etc. anyway much nicer than the Maven output), and Maven is for "machines" (e.g. continous integration, automated build etc.)

Comment: @jhyot I appreciate the explanation with humans vs. machines. I think I now see a bigger picture.